# exclude incoming voice when using android voice recognition API (recognizerIntent)

Tags: android, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, recognizer-intent

I'm developing an app that requieres the voice recognition by using the speech recognizer. I want to get the only result of the outgoing voice call while talking over the telephone but it actually handles both sides of conversation. Does anybody know a way that excludes the incoming voice call when using the voice recognition google api?